# using ng-repeat with dynamically created classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

My problem is as following :

When creating the document manually as following :

```
<div model="image" ctrl="Dropdown">
    <div value="show">Show Images</div>
    <div value="hide">Hide Images</div>
    <div value="showhover">Show Images on Hover</div>
</div>
```

The divs inside the Dropdown are given the correct classes and on mouseover they change, however, when using ng-repeat, the divs created by ng-repeat do not hold the dynamic classes

```
<div wix-model="image" wix-ctrl="Dropdown">
  <div ng-repeat="page in pages" value={{$index}}>
    {{page.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

*the model and ctrl attributes are a part of a UI lib i'm working with.

Is there a way to make those divs behave like manually created ones?
Thank you!

EDIT : 
I was probably unclear,

The following HTML,

```
<div wix-model="image" wix-ctrl="Dropdown">
    <div value="show">Show Images</div>
    <div value="hide">Hide Images</div>
    <div value="showhover">Show Images on Hover</div>
</div>
```

Generates this HTML :

```
<div wix-model="image" wix-ctrl="Dropdown" class="dropdown dropdown-style-1 focus-active"><span class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-down"></span>
    <div class="selected">
        <div data-value="show" data-index="0" class="option current-item">Show Images</div>
    </div>
    <div class="options uilib-scrollbar" style="width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 100%; z-index: 999999; display: block; overflow: auto;">
        <div data-value="show" data-index="0" class="option option-selected dropdown-highlight">Show Images</div>
        <div data-value="hide" data-index="1" class="option">Hide Images</div>
        <div data-value="showhover" data-index="2" class="option">Show Images on Hover</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to push those divs under the wix-model div BEFORE the page loads so that when it does, the divs are already there and will get the correct classes etc?
Thank you!

Comment: wr do u use the ng-class here ?

Comment: `Is there any way to push those divs under the wix-model div BEFORE the page loads` - I don't think it would be possible, because angularjs is a client side framework. First all the files are delivered to client's machine. At this time your `wix-model` would be created, afterwards angularjs would run and your data would be binded to ng-repeat. So basically your div's would come after the page loads. You can use any server side language like java, php if you want those div's to appear before page loading.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd recommend that you figure out a condition or a logic to render the classes. However, according to the information that you've provided, this solution would work good.

```
<div wix-model="image" wix-ctrl="Dropdown">
  <div ng-class="{'Show Images':'show', 'Hide Images':'hide', 'Show Images on Hover':'showhover'}[page.title]" ng-repeat="page in pages" value={{$index}}>
    {{page.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**

I've used an object `$scope.pages` according to the description that you've provided. When you run the below snippet, you can clearly see how those classes are applied.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div wix-model="image">
      <div ng-class="{'Show Images':'show', 'Hide Images':'hide', 'Show Images on Hover':'showhover'}[page.title]" ng-repeat="page in pages" value={{$index}}>
        {{page.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <script>
      var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
  
      myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.pages = [
            {title : 'Show Images', otherprop : 'lorem ipsum'},
            {title : 'Hide Images', otherprop : 'lorem ipsum'},
            {title : 'Show Images on Hover', otherprop : 'lorem ipsum'}
          ];
      }]);
    </script>
  
 </body>

</html>
```

**Output**

```
<div wix-model="image">
    <!-- ngRepeat: page in pages -->
    <div ng-class="{'Show Images':'show', 'Hide Images':'hide', 'Show Images on Hover':'showhover'}[page.title]" ng-repeat="page in pages" value="0" class="ng-binding ng-scope show">
        Show Images
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages -->
    <div ng-class="{'Show Images':'show', 'Hide Images':'hide', 'Show Images on Hover':'showhover'}[page.title]" ng-repeat="page in pages" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope hide">
        Hide Images
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages -->
    <div ng-class="{'Show Images':'show', 'Hide Images':'hide', 'Show Images on Hover':'showhover'}[page.title]" ng-repeat="page in pages" value="2" class="ng-binding ng-scope showhover">
        Show Images on Hover
    </div>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages -->
</div>
```

You can easily see how `show`, `hide` and `showhover` classes are applied.

Comment: doesn't work still, shows the exact same thing, thanks

Comment: @user4370437 I've updated the code. Please ping me if you face any issue.

Comment: Edited my original question, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ng-class directive to achieve that. class1 & class2 are your classes defined in css.

```
<div ng-repeat="page in pages" value={{$index}} ng-class="style">
{{page.title}}
</div>

//Controller Code 
$scope.style = class1;// or class2 according to your requirement
```

Comment: this code will bind the `style` and so style will be same for all the div's. If you change it afterwards, then it will change the class for all the div's with new value.

Comment: @RamanSahasi may be i didnt get the question right. I thought Binding the style for the all the repeat elements is the requirement & changing the style of all the elements when hover event has occured